# Queremos introducir una nueva columna con el total de horas trabajadas de los empleados, teniendo en cuenta media hora de descanso

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Como se ve en la imagen, los trabajadores empiezan a trabajar a las 7 a.m., pero terminan en diferente horario. Teniendo en cuenta que los trabajadores se toman media hora de descanso cada cuatro horas trabajadas. Querríamos saber la formula necesaria para sacar la respuesta de la columna que hemos marcado en rojo.
Aquí tenéis la hoja de cálculos:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y3YmSSuAlm-VtItYkXVkJScETu1d7mofKTUkRN5Yqj0/edit#gid=0

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. Queréis saber cómo hacerlo, pero... ¿Habéis intentado algo? Es más fácil ayudarte si empiezas, aunque tenga errores :)

Comment: Tu enlace va a una hoja en la cual hay que solicitar acceso, si no quieres que en dos años o mas te sigan llegando peticiones para visualizar te recomiendo que lo cambies a público o que lo muestres de otra manera

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y3YmSSuAlm-VtItYkXVkJScETu1d7mofKTUkRN5Yqj0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Creo que necesitáis algo así:

```
=mod(D3-C3;1)-if(mod(D3-C3;1) >time(4;0;0); time(0;30;0); 0)
```

Cambiad las filas/columnas de los D3 y C3 para que os cuadre